# How to apply Mongo DB find command for nested dynamic keys

Tags: regex, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query

Want to search all matching pattern from Mongo DB nested fields with dynamic keys.

DB Structure:

```
_id: 'dsdsdsadadad',
results: {
   tables: {
      jvm: {
        data: [
          {
             Prediction: 1,
             Jvm: 'service_name',
             Status: 'OK'
          },
          {
            second: 'New second set'
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Tried By `$`,

`db.col_name.find('results.tables.jvm.data.$.Jvm': {'$regexp': 'service.*'})`

By using `$i`

`db.col_name.find('results.tables.jvm.data.$i.Jvm': {'$regexp': 'service.*'})`

By giving particular key `0` also,

`db.col_name.find('results.tables.jvm.data.0.Jvm': {'$regexp': 'service.*'})`

No results!

**Expected O/P:**

The above doc and where all Jvm starts with `service*` keyword

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should directly use the dot notation to query an array of nested objects:

```
db.collection.find({ "results.tables.jvm.data.Jvm": { $regex: "service.*" } })
```

MongoDB will try to find every document that contains at least one nested document under `data` having `Jvm` field matching your regex.

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W3ipeU8nf8a)